# "how things work" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Now that the how-things-work site has been closed and in spite of some people wishing to raise the standard, there are a number of questions about the physics of how things such as common machines and appliances work

Is there any consensus on a "how things work" tag?

ps Not really a dupe of [What tag should we use to indicate "how does X work?" ?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/what-tag-should-we-use-to-indicate-how-does-x-work) - I'm intending this for a "how does an air conditioner work" not a "how does gravity work" type question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some (many?) of these questions will likely be off topic, in which case the tags probably don't matter... but for the rest, we do have an [everyday-life](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-life) tag that I think should cover it.

Comment: I think there is something to this, but it is because the questions will be ill-posed, rather than because there won't be a valid underling physics question. Martin's AC example has at it's core the question of how compressive warming/expansive cooling works, *"How does a computer work?"* could be reduced to how to semi-conductor switches work and so on...

Comment: Depends if you regard physics.so as meta for Phys Rev Letters, or as a source of physics answers for people who don't know physics.

Comment: @dmckee: yeah, that's kind of what I was getting at. The thing is, I'd much rather see people actually asking the underlying physics questions, rather than general things like "how does an air conditioner work?"

Comment: @Martin: ideally both, though it does seem like that model doesn't work in practice. In any case now we have the theoretical physics site to be meta.PRL ;-)